# C error and locating TKIGES

Tags: c

I found the answer to this question :

Question:

> /usr/bin/ld: errno: TLS definition in /lib/libc.so.6 section .tbss
>   mismatches non-TLS reference in ./../lib/lib.a(file_op.o)
>   /lib/libc.so.6: could not read symbols: Bad value

Answer:

"What you need to do is this: open the appropriate makefile (i.e. in `TKIGES`), find the line `DEFAULT_INCLUDES`, and add `-include /usr/include/errno.h` to the end."

My question:

Where can I find `TKIGES`? Instead if the above sentence means that i should make change in my makefile, then error still persists.